# Cannot delete a virtual IP in firewall Fortigate 100A

Tags: firewall

The delete button is missing for some virtual IP addresses in menu Firewall->Virtual IP. No policies etc are defined for the Virtual IP. I'm using FortiGate 100A
BR,
Pasi

Answer (score 2):

Double check that no policy is using the virtual IP; I thought I had the same problem, but the policy was hidden because the rules for that interface were collapsed by default, so I missed it (and searching using ctrl-f didn't work).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your greyed out interface is named "test", run this from the CLI to find the dependency that is not letting you delete this.

```
diagnose sys checkused firewall.vip.name test
```